# How to make a stereogram in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

Given a background and a pattern jpg files, is there a quick and easy way to produce a stereogram by using Mathematica? The following picture was produced from Photoshop, spent about half an hour.
[image]

Here is the background tile for creating the blank background below:

[image]

and here is a blank background picture of pebbles:
[image]

Comment: Could you supply the sample background and .jpg image, along with information about or link to "stereogram"?

Comment: What is the hidden image? I can never see them.

Comment: This [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FloatingDiskStereogram/) may be a good place to start. How did you do it in Photoshop?

Comment: Is the hidden image of a person's head?

Comment: It is just simply a circle over the background, for those who cannot see the circle, try stare behind the picture for a while, the 3D circle will come up. Here is a [link](http://www.slicktutorials.com/magic-eye-stereogram) for creating stereogram in Photoshop. And here is a [web site](http://www.easystereogrambuilder.com/3d-stereogram-maker.aspx) for creating stereogram online for free.

Comment: Related: [R. Maeder, *TMJ* (1995) **1**](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v5i1/columns/maeder/index.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's an alternative method which takes a depth map.

**This is a complete change from my original code** - my apologies for doing such a major edit after receiving so many upvotes but it was not quite right before (there were artifacts in the 3D view). This version is based on the description [here](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ece576/FinalProjects/f2007/awh24_mdj23/awh24_mdj23/).

I upsample the pattern image and depth map before creating the stereogram, and afterwards downsample the result back to the correct size. This is to allow a greater number of depth planes without having to explicitly interpolate to get sub-pixel shifts.

For better performance I use a compiled function to do the actual pixel-copying core of the algorithm. I have used compilation to C but for those without a C compiler it will work just as well (but a bit slower) using the WVM.

The final function `stereogram` takes as arguments the pattern image, the depth image and the desired number of tiles in width and height. The fourth optional argument is the maximum pixel shift in the upsampled image - this is also the number of distinct depth planes.

```
shift = Compile[{
    {im, _Real, 3}, {d, _Integer, 2}, {nx2, _Integer},
    {ny, _Integer}, {w, _Integer}, {h, _Integer}},
   Block[{i = im}, Do[i[[y, x + d[[y, x]]]] = i[[y, x - d[[y, x]]]],
     {y, h ny}, {x, 1 + nx2, 2 w nx2 - nx2}]; i],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

sg[pattern_, depthmap_, copies_, maxshift_] :=
 Module[{nx, ny, p, w, h, i, d},
  {nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[pattern];
  p = If[OddQ[nx], ImageCrop[pattern, {nx = nx - 1, ny}], pattern];
  {w, h} = copies;
  i = ImageData @ ImageAssemble@ConstantArray[p, {h, w}];
  d = depthmap ~ImageCrop~ {w nx, h ny} ~ColorConvert~ "Grayscale";
  d = Round[nx/2 - maxshift Clip[ImageData @ d, {0, 1}]];
  Image[shift[i, d, nx/2, ny, w, h]]]

stereogram[pattern_Image, depthmap_Image, copies_List: {5, 5}, maxshift_: 40] :=
 sg[pattern ~ImageResize~ Scaled[5],
   depthmap ~ImageResize~ Scaled[5],
   copies, maxshift] ~ImageResize~ Scaled[1/5]
```

Example:

```
pattern = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKct.jpg"];
depthmap = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJf51.png"];

stereogram[pattern, depthmap, {6, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, it pops!

Comment: Cool, I tried to follow your method to get depth map for the 'bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"]' like:'deptmap = 
 ListSurfacePlot3D[bunny, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, Ticks -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 5]  ], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"] ', the outcome was not satisfactory. How to get a dept map from a 3D model?

Comment: @user16069, it should be fairly easy to create a depth map from a 3D model. You just need to shade each vertex according to its distance from the viewpoint. If you need help with it I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: For those of us not yet on V10, could you post a version without `RadialGradientImage`. I tried using `depth = ImageCrop[
  ImageAdjust@
   Rasterize[
    DensityPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
     ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False], 
    ImageSize -> {w nx, h ny}], {w nx, h ny}]`, But all I'm getting are `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in`, when running the shift part. (Still +1:)

Comment: I guess something like `ImageAdjust@
 Rasterize@
  DensityPlot[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) ( 
     Cos[6 (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])] - 0.5), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, PlotRange -> All]` Could work instead of `RadialGradientImage`

Comment: @Ajasja, the threading error is because `Rasterize` gives an RGB image and the depth map needs to be grayscale. You could use `ColorConvert`, or just create the values directly in a `Table` (I extract the `ImageData` in the next line anyway).

Answer (score 14):

Here is something to play with. The method comes from the [tutorial](http://www.slicktutorials.com/magic-eye-stereogram). The gui uses `ImageMultiply` and `SetAlphaChannel` to copy a piece of the background defined by `object`. Then it uses `ImagePerspectiveTransformation` and `TranslationTransform` to move the copy to a new position. Finally `ImageCompose` is used to paste the copied section at the new position on the original background. The tutorial mentioned a second copy to eliminate an artifact, so I threw in a second copy to see the effect.

```
(* get a texture *)
texture = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKct.jpg"];
tdims = ImageDimensions@texture;

(* add some noise *)
texture = ImageEffect[texture, {"GaussianNoise", 0.1}];

(* tile the noisy texture *)
background = ImagePad[texture, {{0, 5*First@tdims}, {0, 2*Last@tdims}}, "Periodic"];
bdims = ImageDimensions@background;

(* create an object to hide *)
object = ImageCrop@Image@Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0}, bdims], White, 
 Disk[bdims/2 - {First@bdims/6, 0}, 0.45*First@tdims]},ImageSize -> bdims]

Manipulate[
  ImageCompose[
  ImageCompose[
   background, 
   ImagePerspectiveTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{shift, 0}]]],
   ImagePerspectiveTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{shift - x, 0}]]] &@
   SetAlphaChannel[ImageMultiply[background, #], #] &@object, 
{shift,0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Autostereogram manipulate]

Edit: Don't forget the bonus decoder

```
Manipulate[
 ImageDifference[#, 
    ImagePerspectiveTransformation[#,TranslationTransform[{t, 0}]]
 ] &@autoStereogramImage,
{t,0,1}]
```

Comment: Great, but I get lost about your last edit, what is `autoSterogramImage` for. And is it possible to create more than a single layer for the stereo image?

Comment: autostereogram is any Magic-Eye or similar image, like the image in my answer. By playing with the slider, the Bonus decoder will reveal the hidden object without requiring you to do crazy eye tricks. You can get more than a single layer, and a multiple hidden objects as well. Just copy other sections of the picture and shift them by different amounts.

Comment: If we can add more layers, can't we add a 3d image/plot?

Comment: @P.Fonseca, I started with that idea, but first you need to take a 3D plot, convert it to a depth image, and then convert the smooth depths to a small set of layers, kind of like converting a sphere into a ball of Lego blocks. I think converting a 3D plot to a depth image warrants its own question here on SE.

Comment: The question about creating a depth image has been [asked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57296/how-to-make-a-depth-map-from-a-3d-model) and collectively [answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57947/9391).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative for making a stereogram:

Download and import a [3D object file](http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/rabbit-97792.html) into Mathematica, which is something looks like this:

[image]

Assuming that the extracted .obj file located on the root of your C: drive, 
Load and make a pose of the rabbit in Mathematica:

```
Clear[vpdata, vvdata, vpdata2, vvdata2, vpD, vvD];
rabbit = Import["c:\\rabbit.obj" ];
f[a_] := (Show[rabbit, Background -> Black,
   ViewPoint -> a[[1]],
   ViewVertical -> a[[2]],
   ImageSize -> {70, 70}] )

vpdata = {-3.0, 0.3 , 1.6};
vvdata = {-1.2 , 0.9, 0.3 };
vpdata2 = {-2.4 , 0.1, 2.4};
vvdata2 = {-1.1, 0.9, 0.4};
vpD = vpdata2 - vpdata;
vvD = vvdata2 - vvdata;
```

making a list of total 9 slightly different posing rabbits:

```
imgNo = 8;
vpFin = Table[{{
     vpdata[[1]] + vpD[[1]]*t/imgNo,
     vpdata[[2]] + vpD[[2]]*t/imgNo,
     vpdata[[3]] + vpD[[3]]*t/imgNo},
    {vvdata[[1]] + vvD[[1]]*t/imgNo,
     vvdata[[2]] + vvD[[2]]*t/imgNo,
     vvdata[[3]] + vvD[[3]]*t/imgNo} }, {t, 0, imgNo }];

imArr = ImageResize[#, {70, 70}] & /@ f /@ vpFin;
```

combing the tiles into strips:

```
bgband = Graphics[ {}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> {70*(imgNo + 1), 70}] ;
background = 
  Graphics[ {}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> {70*(imgNo + 1), 5*70}] ;
For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++,
    bgband2 = ImageCompose[ bgband, imArr[[i]], {35 + (i - 1)*70, 35}];
   bgband = bgband2;
  ];
For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++,
    bgband3 = ImageCompose[ bgband, imArr[[5]], {35 + (i - 1)*70, 35}];
   bgband = bgband3;
  ];
```

produce the stereogram:

```
bground = ImageCompose[background, bgband3, {315, 35}];
bground = ImageCompose[bground, bgband3, {315, 105}];
bground = ImageCompose[bground, bgband2, {315, 175}] ;
bground = ImageCompose[bground, bgband3, {315, 245}];
bground = ImageCompose[bground, bgband3, {315, 315}]
```

[image]

Note the rabbits in the third row. And the following picture was produced by the same method:

[image]

Comment: You can get a built in bunny with `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]`.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't help my self, so here is a 3D (V9 compliant) bunny:)
(Some artifacts, perhaps of pixels being shifted too much are still present...)

```
pattern = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKct.jpg"];
{nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[pattern];
pt = Flatten[ImageData[pattern], 1];
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];

{w, h} = {8, 8};(*how many copies of the pattern*)
y = Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[nx Mod[i, ny], w nx], {i, 0, h ny - 1}];
x = Range[w h nx ny];

depth = ColorConvert[
  ImageCrop[
   Rasterize[
    ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, 
     ColorFunction -> (Glow[GrayLevel[#3]] &), Mesh -> None, 
     Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 10}, 
     Axes -> False], ImageSize -> Round[{w nx, h ny}*0.6]], {w nx, 
    h ny}], "Grayscale"]

shift = Round[
   6 Flatten[Accumulate[Partition[#, nx]] & /@ ImageData@depth]];
Image[Partition[pt[[y + Mod[x + shift, nx, 1]]], w nx]]
```

[image: 3D bunny]

Comment: Regarding the artifacts, I think I may have the algorithm slightly wrong, though  I can't see where. When I get a chance I will try to fix it.

Comment: @SimonWoods Yes, I had to reduce the scaling factor before flatten to get better results (but less depth). Reducing the size of the bunny also helped.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late to the party, I found that there's no way to add texture to the rabbit using @Simon's method, thus I created one of my own. Effect first!

[image: sample]

One rabbit only, correct texture for the rabbit for most part.

The code is as follows, and could be downloaded [here](https://github.com/wjxway/Stereogram-Mathematica):

```
mappedstereogram[img_Image, depth_Image, bg_Image, n_List: {5, 3}, 
  shift_: 40, supersampling_: 2, filter_: 1] :=
 Module[{imgbg, imgmap, imgdep, 
   dimo = Round[ImageDimensions[bg]*supersampling, 2], l, conn},
  imgbg = 
   ImageData@
    ImageAssemble@
     ConstantArray[
      ImageResize[ColorConvert[bg, "RGB"], dimo, 
       Resampling -> "Linear"], Reverse@n];
  imgmap = 
   ImageData@
    ImageCrop[
     ImageResize[ColorConvert[img, "RGB"], Scaled@supersampling, 
      Resampling -> "Linear"], n dimo];
  imgdep = 
   Round[dimo[[1]]/2 - 
     shift Clip[
       ImageData@
        ImageCrop[
         ImageResize[ColorConvert[depth, "Grayscale"], 
          Scaled@supersampling, Resampling -> "Linear"], n dimo], {0, 
        1}]];

  l = Length@imgdep[[1]];

  Table[
   conn = 
    ConnectedComponents@
     Graph@Select[
       Flatten[MapIndexed[{(l + #2[[1]]) <-> (#2[[1]] - #1), (l + #2[[
               1]]) <-> (#2[[1]] + #1)} &, imgdep[[i]]], 1], 
       0 < #[[2]] <= l &];

   MapThread[
    With[{res = 
        Select[Thread@{#1, imgmap[[i, #1]]}, Max@#[[2]] != 0. &]}, 
      imgbg[[i, #2]] = 
       ConstantArray[
        If[Length@res != 0., SortBy[res, #[[1]] &][[1, 2]], 
         imgbg[[i, #2[[1]]]]], Length@#2]] &, {Pick[conn, 
       UnitStep[l - conn], 0] - l, Pick[conn, UnitStep[l - conn], 1]}]

   , {i, Floor[(Length@imgbg - 
        supersampling ImageDimensions[depth][[2]])/2], 
    Ceiling[(Length@imgbg + 
        supersampling ImageDimensions[depth][[2]])/2]}];

  ImageResize[MedianFilter[Image@imgbg, filter], 
   Scaled[1/supersampling], Resampling -> "Linear"]
  ]
```

input are a texture image `img`, a corresponding depth image `depth`, and a background image `bg`.

First three lines of code are responsible for formatting the image to the same scale. Then we start to create the stereogram using the following equation:

$$f(x,y,h(x,y))=g(x-\alpha h(x,y),y)=g(x+\alpha h(x,y),y)$$

where $f$ and $g$ are pixel value on the object and on the image plane, $\alpha$ is the difference of viewing angle of two eyes, and $h(x,y)$ are the depth of the image.

We first find out the correlation between $f$ and $g$ by constructing a graph and calculate its connected components. A connected component like $f(x_0)\leftrightarrow g(x_1)\leftrightarrow f(x_2)\leftrightarrow g(x_3), f(x_2)\leftrightarrow g(x_4)$ means these positions should share the same pixel value!

Then by using the texture given by $f(x_0)$ to render $g(x_1), g(x_3),g(x_4)$, we can have the correct stereogram.

To avoid defects, super sampling and `MedianFilter` are implemented.

This method can be used together with @Simons' to get augment visual effects:

[image: augment]