# How to make a depth map from a 3D model?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, rendering

Given a 3D .obj model, for example [a rabbit](http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/rabbit-97792.html). How can we make a depth map out of it? Any idea or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
model = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}];
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[model];

Rasterize @ RegionPlot3D[region, ColorFunction -> (Glow[GrayLevel[#3]] &),
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 10}, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Mostly the same as @SimonWoods, but it runs on V9:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> (Glow[GrayLevel[#3]] &), Mesh -> None, 
 Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 10}, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To avoid perspecitve distortion, change `ViewPoint` to `{0, 0, Infinity}`.

Comment: @shrx the rabbit coordinates go from `0.03` to `0.2`, so `10` is almost `Infinity`

Answer (score 5):

The ability of adjusting the viewpoint and position of a model before obtaining its depth-map is necessary in most cases. By adopting the answers provided by the nice guys here, I obtained an alternative method in which the viewpoint and position of the model can be adjusted right before producing its depth-map. And function `DiscretizeGraphics` was used instead of `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` to avoid the *boundary curves self-intersect* problem.

Import your model first, for example a cow:

```
model = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}];
```

or download a model from a [link here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cyr4pood1197is/turtle.obj), for example a turtle, then import into Mathematica:

```
Import["c:\\turtle.obj"];
```

Prepare a graph for viewpoint and position adjustment:

```
vp = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint];
vv = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewVertical];
vpoint = {};
vvertical = {};
Show[model, Background -> Black,
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[
   vp, (vp = #; vpoint = # ) &],
 ViewVertical -> Dynamic[
   vv, (vv = #; vvertical = # ) &],
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
```

[image]

(Drag for rotation, Shift-Drag for position, Crt-Drag for zooming)

And run the following code for the depth-map when you are happy with the adjustments:

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics[model];
Rasterize@RegionPlot3D[region, ColorFunction -> (Glow[GrayLevel[#3]] &),
  ViewPoint -> vpoint,
  ViewVertical -> vvertical,
  Background -> Black,
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> None]
```

[image: rig]

Comment: You should probably incorporate the code from Timothy Wofford's answer as well, otherwise you're still colouring by the original $z$-coordinates of the model rather than the depth from the camera. http://i.stack.imgur.com/wFmRm.png

Comment: and maybe a `ViewCenter` and `ViewAngle` to complete the camera specification?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation to help with different points of view.

```
data = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "VertexData"];
viewPoint = {-1, -1, -1};
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(EuclideanDistance[#, viewPoint] & /@ data)

ListSurfacePlot3D[data, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, 
 ViewPoint -> viewPoint,
 ColorFunction -> (Glow[GrayLevel[
   (max - EuclideanDistance[{#1, #2, #3}, viewPoint])/(max - min)
 ]] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Mesh -> None, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False]
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Rahul Narain for pointing out my oversight, and thanks to Timothy Wofford for his suggestion. Here, I revised my code as below. I still keep on using the function  `DiscretizeGraphics` because I can't get rid of the [ugly boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AMUI.jpg) produced by `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

Code for viewpoint & position adjustment:

```
model = Import["c:\\turtle.obj"];
vp = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint];
vv = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewVertical];
vc = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewCenter];
va = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewAngle];
vpoint = {-0.5  , 0.8 , 3 };
vvertical = {0.1 , 2 , 0.5};
vcenter = {{0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 }, {0.5 , 0.5 }};
vangle = 0.2;
Show[model, Background -> Black,
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp, (vp = #; vpoint = #) &],
 ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; vvertical = #) &],
 ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc, (vc = #; vcenter = #) &],
 ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va, (va = #; vangle = #) &],
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
```

[image]
(Drag for rotation, Shift-Drag for position, Alt-Drag for zooming)

Code for producing the depth-map after the adjustment:

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics[model];
vdata = Import["c:\\turtle.obj" , "VertexData"];
viewPoint = vpoint;
{min, max} = {Min@#, Max@#} &@(EuclideanDistance[#, viewPoint] & /@ vdata);
Rasterize@RegionPlot3D[region, 
  ColorFunction -> (Glow[
      GrayLevel[ (max - EuclideanDistance[{#1, #2, #3}, viewPoint])/(max - min)]] &),
  ViewPoint -> vpoint,
  ViewVertical -> vvertical,
  ViewCenter -> vcenter,
  ViewAngle -> vangle,
  Background -> Black,
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> None]
```

[image]