# Stereogram in Mathematica: inverse question

Tags: image-processing, image3d

I've seen in [this wonderful post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57034/how-to-make-a-stereogram-in-mathematica) that it's possible to create a stereogram in Mathematica.

But I didn't found anything regardless the inverse problem. Given a stereogram, is possible to retrieve the hidden image (heightmap)?

For example, given this image:

[image]

Is possible somehow to retrieve its height map?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An ugly but working solution:

[image: output]

First we should estimate the period of the background patter:

```
shift = Block[{img = ste, x, corr},
   corr = 
    ImageData[
      ImageCorrelate[ImageAssemble[{img, img}], img, 
       CorrelationDistance, Padding -> None]][[1]];
   FindPeaks[-Norm /@ corr, 10][[2, 1]] - 1];
```

This code do not always work, so you might want to take a look at `corr` and choose a proper `shift` value manually. Then we manually set up the maximum possible height of this stereogram, symbolized by `maxdist`.

```
sft = Round[shift/2];
maxdist = 20;
```

Then, point by point, we compare pixel `{i-sft+h,j}` and `{i+sft-h,j}`, for fixed `i` and `j`, we choose `h` which minimize the difference between these two pixels. However, due to interpolation issues, we might want to interpolate the data.

```
subdiv[lst_, n_] := 
 Prepend[Catenate[Rest[Subdivide[##, n]] & @@@ Partition[lst, 2, 1]], 
  lst[[1]]]
myMedianFilter[dat_, n_] := 
 MovingMedian[Join[Reverse@dat[[;; n]], dat, Reverse@dat[[-n ;; -1]]],
   2 n + 1]
hdat = Block[{div = 20, kl = 2, dattemp}, 
     dattemp = (Table[
           TakeSmallest[(Norm /@ 
                subdiv[Table[#[[i - sft - 1 + j]] - #[[i + sft + 1 - 
                    j]], {j, 0, maxdist + 2}], div]) -> "Index", 
             1][[1]], {i, sft + 2, Length[#] - sft - 2}] - 1.)/div - 1;
     MapThread[
      If[Abs[#1 - #2] < .2 #3 + .5, #1, #2] &, {dattemp, 
       myMedianFilter[dattemp, kl], 
       StandardDeviationFilter[dattemp, kl]}]
     ] & /@ ImageData[ste];

MedianFilter[Image[hdat/17], 10]
```

Here measures are taken to filter out anomolies, however, they don't always work... might require some tweak here.

With better quality images or self-generated images, the result can be much more satisfying. For example, for this image:

[image: input]

the result will be:

[image: output]

Comment: That's wonderful!!!

Comment: @Jepessen not quite, there should be plenty of places to optimize, and the speed could definitely be improved greatly……