# How to make a stereograph?

Tags: graphics

I’m interested in creating my own stereo graph like this one below.  These got popular a few years back in malls.  If you focus on a point passed the screen a 3d object appears in 3d. I’m wondering if there is a way to generate my own with my an object that I choose.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Looks like [57034](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57034/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the first paper to describe the algorithms:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225365518_Software_for_generating_auto-random-dot_stereograms